# Nerdcomment {% comment%} ... {% endcomment %}

Tags: vim, nerdcommenter

With the `Nerdcommenter` plugin, is there an easy way to comment out lines in a django template? I know we could use `{% comment%} ... {% endcomment %}` to comment lines, but it is not one of the shortcuts in `Nerdcommenter` I think.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[NERD commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) uses `'commentstring'` to decide how to make a comment.

Add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/htmldjango.vim`:

```
set commentstring={%\ comment\ %}%s{%\ endcomment\ %}
```

For more help see:

```
:h NERDComInstallation
:h 'commentstring'
```